# Regex expiration date MM/YYYY

Tags: regex

I'm trying to find a regex pattern to validate credit card expiration date. The format is MM/YYYY

```
00/0000 -> Not accepted
02/0000 -> Not accepted
00/2016 -> Not accepted
02/2016 -> accepted
12/2016 -> acceptedenter code here
13/2016 -> Not accepted
```

the two number of the year must be 20
the year doesn't be under 2016
Any ideas? 
thanks

Comment: Regex changed a little because it would've matched `00/...`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**You want this** -- not that it's the only solution:

```
(0[1-9]|10|11|12)/20[0-9]{2}$
```

---

**PS:** This requires the `-E` tag if being used with `grep`.

**PPS:** This answer assumes that the expiration date is at the end of a line.

**PPPS:** If you want an explanation, *give me a ring.* :)

Comment: Thank you so much for fast answer

Comment: @AyoubichEscobar: Is it working for you?

Comment: yeah it's work thank you ^^

Comment: @AyoubichEscobar: Great! Please accept it by clicking the checkmark. Then I'll get credit for my answer and people will know the problem was solved. :)

Comment: You probably want `0[1-9]` in the first regex group so it doesn't match `00`

Comment: @BrendanAbel: True. Thanks for pointing that out.